# PL SQL relationship and procedure issues

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to ask some help with pl/sql oracle. I am trying to figure out this object oriented database stuff but not much success so far. I am into programming and i understand rdbms as well, already managed some complex database but this object oriented is over my understanding.
So the task is the following:
There are teachers and students. need to make a timetable which has two type of lessons. day and afternoon.
day class can have maximum 10 students and afternoon max 5.

the followings i have so far:

```
/*create student type and table*/
create type student_typ as object(
st_id char(3),
st_name varchar(50)
)
create table student_tbl of student_typ(
st_id primary key not null,
st_name not null
)

/*create teacher type and table*/
create type teacher_typ as object(
tr_id char(3),
tr_name varchar(50)
)
create table teacher_tbl of teacher_typ(
tr_id primary key not null,
tr_name not null
)

/*create array type to store the student id-s*/
create type students_arr as varray(20) of char(3);

/*create table for timetable*/
create table timetable_tbl(
t_ID char(5),
t_Date date,
t_Time varchar(5), /*store time format as 12:00*/
t_Type char(1),
teacher ref teacher_typ scope is teacher_tbl,
students students_arr,
constraint chk_type check(t_Type='D' or t_Type='N')
)

/*insert values into the tables*/
insert into teacher_tbl values ('t01','bob');
insert into teacher_tbl values ('t02','smith');
insert into student_tbl values ('s01','lara');
insert into student_tbl values ('s02','john');

/*insert values into timetable*/
insert into timetable_tbl( select 't01','01-Apr-17','09:00','D',ref(t),students_arr('s01','s02') from teacher_tbl t where t.tr_ID='t01');
insert into timetable_tbl( select 't02','01-Apr-17','19:00','N',ref(t),students_arr('s01') from teacher_tbl t where t.tr_ID='t02');

/*display timetable records*/
select t_ID, t_Date, t_Time, t_Type, deref(teacher).tr_ID,deref(teacher).tr_Name, students from timetable_tbl;

/*create procedure to add new student*/
create or replace procedure Add_Student(
v_id in student_tbl.st_id%type,
v_name in student_tbl.st_name%type,
verror out varchar2 )
is begin
insert into student_tbl (st_id,st_name) values (v_id,v_name);
commit;
exception when others then
verror := sqlerrm;
end;

/*call add_student procedure*/
declare
verror varchar2(500);
begin
Add_Student('s03','sam',verror);
end;
```

So that is what i have so far. The questions are the next.

- Is this the right way to do this?
- how can i reference the students in the varray? i have tried ref as with the teacher ref but no result at all?
  students student_arr ref student_typ scope is student_tbl; this code is not working.
  the students_arr array should accept only existing records from student table
- how can i create a procedure for timetable? because the main thing there is when the t_Type is "D" then the student_arr should allow maximum 10 values
  and if the t_Type is "N" then the student_arr should allow maximum 5 values only. i Should do something like add_record procedure for timetable and using if statement but i am not sure it would be a good idea. 
  if t_type='D' then
  if students.count<=10
  or 
  if t_type='N' then
  if students.count<=5

Im kind of stucked now. I have watched a lot of tutorials about pl sql but got even more confused. The annoying things is that i managed the same with
rdbms (sql server) and java in no time. But this language and object database got me hard now.

Any help would be appropriated!

Comment: I don't see a PL/SQL question specifically. The question seems to be around handling [object reference functions in SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions005.htm), which may be interesting academically but I am pretty confident that nobody has ever used one in any real-world scenario since their introduction in 8i. Also, unrelated, some of your string types are `char` and not `varchar2`. `char` is rarely a useful type.

Comment: I tried it and all the code works. The interesting `deref` is like an implicit FK lookup - neat. I seem to recall a Steven Feuerstein article suggesting practical uses for it, although I can't think of any right now. I think the general "right way to do this" is to avoid collection and ref columns unless you have a specific need for them.

Comment: As i mentioned i am not really clear with this object oriented database stuff. I know programming java, c# and many more and rdbms but this stuff i dont understand. Maybe i just missunderstand the whole oo database concept. What i need help with is to create the scenario in plsql in the right way.

Comment: i have read that char uses fixed memory size and varchar2 is dynamic and is good for ID-s and stuff. Also i have seen it in many tutorials but to be honest i have never used it in any other database.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need an OO approach for this, and can't use procedural PL/SQL? That is what most practitioners would regard as the right way.

Comment: Regarding `char`, where did you read that? All it does it blank-pad any non-null value out to its maximum, for no good reason except that the ANSI committee put it in the standard so Oracle provided it for compatibility. The only practical use for it is in building fixed-width reports, though even then you have to handle nulls, and nobody builds fixed-width reports anyway. Other than that it's literally a waste of space as well as a source of potential bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the `students` array using the `table()` function:

```
select t_id, t_date, t_time, t_type, deref(teacher).tr_id,deref(teacher).tr_name
     , s.column_value as student
from   timetable_tbl cross join table(students) s;
```

You'll also see that join written as

```
from   timetable_tbl, table(students) s;
```

which looks neater in this context but I've officially switched to ANSI join syntax.

Since `students_arr` is a generic varray of varchar2 it has no attribute names, hence the default name [`column_value`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns004.htm).

As for the procedure to insert timetables, if it takes a `students_arr` varray parameter named `p_students`, yes just check `p_students.count` against the `t_type` value. (You can't use a `cardinality()` function in a check constraint unfortunately, which otherwise might have been the declarative approach.)

Regarding "the right way to do this", use ordinary, normalised relational tables unless you have a good use for the object/nested table stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed i was not clear about the questions. So here is the things again but in a simplified way.

There is a person class which holds info about persons. And there is a test class which holds other info like a timetable but it holds persons in a column. So it is a multi-valued column which i can manage with either using varray or nested table type.
[image]

The problem is how to use ref in this way. I can use ref for a single object but not in collection.

```
/*create person type and table*/
create type person_ty as object(
pid varchar(3),
pName varchar(50)
);
create table person_tbl of person_ty;

/*create table which will be used as nested table*/
create type nest_ty as object(
tID varchar(3),
person ref person_ty
);
create type nest_tbl as table of nest_ty;

/*create table for test*/
create table test_tbl(
tID varchar(3),
tDate date,
persons nest_tbl
)nested table persons store as persons;
```

- so how can i insert data into the test table?

i know a single nested table without ref type would be:

```
insert into test_tbl values ('123','12-dec-17', nest_tbl(
nest_ty('123','p01'),
nest_ty('345','p06')
));
```

and i know that insert data with a single ref type looks like this:

```
insert into test_tbl 
select '123', '12-dec-17', ref(a) from person_tbl a where a.pID='p01';
```

Again i am very new with oodb and plsql so my questions might not be clear or make no sense. In that case im sorry.
Still appropriate all kind of help.